# Imagebutton on top of a google mapview

Tags: google-maps, transparent, imagebutton, android

I'm placing an `ImageButton` on top of a `MapView`.  The `ImageButton` is a save icon with a transparent background.  It looks great on my Windows Phone 7 app but on my Android app the background is not really transparent.  As you can see the transparent background looks like a big square `Button`.

How can I truly make the background transparent?  Picture and xml pasted below.
Thanks,
Gary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMAP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Map"
    style="@style/bigtype" />
```

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="mykeyhere"
    android:clickable="true" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/save_white" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to make the background transparent. By default the background is of gray color.

The code should be like this,

```
<ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/save_white"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: even though A.A's answer was less code, this seems better practice.  thanks. Gary

Answer (score 1):

don't use `android:src` but use background instead

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/save_white" />
```

Comment: thanks for responding with an answer that works fine but I prefer the answer from VendettaDroid as it seems better to understand and maybe less likely to get broken going forward.